Update columns of DataTable after having the data from server
I need a solution for my problem. I have a Django app where I use DataTables with server-side processing, the table template is dynamic for all the models I have, I just pass the columns (a list of dicts with data, name and title) within the context of the template, pretty straightforward...
def my_page_view(request):
    columns = generate_datatables_columns("MyModel")

    return render(
        request,
        "my_page.html",
        {"columns": columns}
    )

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var columns = [];
        {% for col in columns %}
            var jsObject = {
                {% for key, value in col.items %}
                    "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}",
                {% endfor %}
            };
            columns.push(jsObject);
        {% endfor %}

        var table = $('#my-table').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/my/url",
                "type": "GET",
            },
            "columns": columns,
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="my-table" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for column in columns %}
                <th id="dt_col_{{column.data}}">{{ column.name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

After that, I needed to make some changes on the columns, but depending on the data received, meaning I should be able to update my columns inside the DataTable definition after having the data. To make the idea clearer, the following code represents one of the attempts I tried, using ajax.dataSrc prop:
var table = $('#my-table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/my/url",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            var data = json.data;
            var newColumns = columns;

            // make changes on data and newColumns variables with some conditions...
            
            // here should update the datatable columns with the value of newColumns.

            return data;
        }
    },
    "columns": columns,
});

With this method I couldn't find a way to update the columns, I tried also other ways like using drawCallback, or custom ajax function, but I always end up with a dead-end.
I will be really grateful if someone helped me with that.
